# Geoserver layer not showing in small scale (after 1:506)

Tags: geoserver, wms

I'm trying to figure out why some of my layers are not rendering in smaller scale. I have one layer that noticed what goes below 1:506 but my newest layers are not..
Is there someone who might have had same problem? What are all settings I can configure when speaking about geoserver layers?

I checked layer settings but all are same in both.. Tried with styling but no help there either. WMS settings checked also but one layer works like it should so don't think it's there

Comment: Whate are the layers stored? What style are you using? What does the log file say?

Comment: Layers are stored in postgres. Styling is made with SLD. There is no log after I scroll below 1:506

Comment: turn your logging level up to GeoTools Dev and try again